# R inverse of logical operators returning nothing

Tags: r, logical-operators

I have many columns of data that all have values of either 0, 1, or NA. For one table, I'm trying to get observations with at least one 1 in any column, so I'm using something like

```
subset(mydata, x == 1 | y == 1 | z == 1)
```

which works fine. For the second table, I'm trying to get observations with no 1 in any column, so I'm using something like

```
subset(mydata, x != 1 & y != 1 & z != 1)
```

which returns 0 observations. Considering that I have 200,000 observations total, and the first table contains ~70,000, it only makes sense to me that its inverse contains ~130,000, but this is not the case. Does anyone know what I can do here?

Comment: I've also tried subset(mydata,!(x==1 | y==1 | z==1)), and the result is still nothing.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.